# Optimizing css delivery not loading the css file in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Optimizing css delivery in pagespeed insights not loading the css file.
I have tried loading the css file by using jquery but the problem is css is not loading.

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

if($(".bs-example").size()>0){
        if (document.createStyleSheet){
            document.createStyleSheet('<?php echo base_url();?>theme/css/style.css');
        }
        else {
            $("head").append($("<link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php echo base_url();?>theme/css/style.css' type='text/css' media='screen' />"));
        }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<body>

<div class="bs-example"></div>
```

Comment: Have you set your base url in config.php don't leave it blank. `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 yes i have set in my config file : $config['base_url'] = 'http://www.staging.website.com/'

Answer (score 0):

CSS assets should be included in the HTML header document with `<link>` tag.

While JS assets, including JQuery Ready function should be after the `</body>` closing tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Website</title>
    <link rel="path/to/css/file"/>
    <style>
        /*your custom CSS*/
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    HTML Body
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"/>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    /*code*/
});
</script>
</html>
```

This way, the CSS will be delivered first, and JQuery Ready function will only be executed after it detect that the page DOM has all been loaded and it's safe to run the JavaScript inside. JQuery Ready function.

Comment: Css links i have added in header file only